# Visual Studio 2015 project binding issue with SonarQube

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarlint-vs

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and installed SonarLint Version 2.9.0. Getting below error when I try to bind solution with the SonarQube project. I couldn't find any references to resolve this issue.

---

Binding solution to SonarQube project: Started
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Discovering solution projects

Included projects:

- src\xxx.Core\xxx.Core.csproj
- src\xxx.Core.Common\xxx.Core.Common.csproj
- src\xxx.Core.Txxxxxxxxxxxx\xxx.Core.Txxxxxxxxxxxx.csproj

  Excluded projects:
- src\UnitTest\xxx.CoreTests\xxx.CoreTests.csproj
- src\UnitTest\xxx.Core.CommonTests\xxx.Core.CommonTests.csproj
- src\UnitTest\xxx.Core.TxxxxxxxxxxxxTests\xxx.Core.TxxxxxxxxxxxxTests.csproj

  You can change the exclusion options via the SonarLint project-level context menu i.e. Solution Explorer -> Select project(s)

Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):

Successfully downloaded quality profile. Name: 'xxxx.Net Rules', Key: 'cs-xxxx-net-rules-20246', Language: 'C#'

Unexpected error during workflow execution: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: numberOfIncrements.

---

**Try #2 Log**

Connecting to SonarQube server: https://xxxxx.xxxx..net/

Connecting to SonarQube server: Detecting server plugins

Discovered a supported plugin: Language: 'C#', Minimum version: '5.0'

Discovered an unsupported plugin: Language: 'VB.NET', Minimum version: '3.0'

Connecting to SonarQube server: Succeeded

Connecting to SonarQube server: Downloading server settings.

Binding solution to SonarQube project: Started

Binding solution to SonarQube project: Discovering solution projects

Included projects:

- ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.csproj

  Excluded projects:
- None (for selected SonarQube project's quality profile)

  You can change the exclusion options via the SonarLint project-level context menu i.e. Solution Explorer -> Select project(s)

Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):

Successfully downloaded quality profile. Name: 'xxxxx .Net Rules', Key: 'cs-xxxxx-net-rules-20246', Language: 'C#'

Unexpected error during workflow execution: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Parameter name: numberOfIncrements.

---

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any VB.Net project within your solution? For now the only ticket opened linked to this kind of issue is this one: [SVS-132](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SVS-132?jql=project%20%3D%20SVS%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20priority%20%3D%20Critical%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC) and is linked to having some VB.Net project and no VB.Net plugin.

---

EDIT:

We have created a ticket for this bug ([here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SVS-140)). But you should keep in mind that SonarLint for VS will not display warnings/errors from third party plugins (FxCop, StyleCop...) because we want to control the quality of the user experience within SonarLint. So in your case with no rule from SonarC# (C# plugin) enabled the connected mode will bring nothing.

Comment: I don't have any VB.Net project in the solution. All are C# projects in the solution.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. Can I ask which SQ version you are binding to? Also what are the available plugins (i.e. only C# or also Fxcop and/or others)?

Comment: SQ Version 5.6.2.  has Stylecop, ReSharper, CodeMaid and other Azure related plugins

Comment: I haven't managed to reproduce the issue yet. Could you try to bind to the same SQ and same project from a simple C# ConsoleApp and tell me if you are experiencing the same behavior? Also, could you confirm you have posted the full log? Because based on the log and the issue we should either have a message like "Installing NuGet package {0} for project {1}" or "Language for project '{0}' is not matching any of the available quality profile's languages"

Comment: I getting the same error message while trying to bind the same SQ and same project from a simple C# console app.  Yes, this is the full log from the Output window. I have included the sonarlint log for this activity in the question under section Try#2 log

Comment: I think I figured out what is the issue. Could you please give me the Deployment xml section (or just the number of items in the NuGetPackages subection) resulting from the call to this api: YOUR_SQ_SERVER:PORT/api/qualityprofiles/export?name=NAME_OF_YOUR_QUALITY_PROFILE&language=cs&exporterKey=roslyn-cs. You could either post it here or send it to me at amaury.leve@sonarsource.com. Thank you

Comment: May I know where I can find the Deployment.xml..?

Comment: You need to copy (update it accordingly to your quality profile) the URL I gave you (example: http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/export?name=Sonar+way&language=cs&exporterKey=roslyn-cs) and copy the deployment section of the result of this query (it is a XML result).

Comment: I have sent the XML file to your mail id. Let me know in case any further details is needed.